# Multiple or single NetworkManager in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

ok so I'm trying to get multiple matches going in an online multiplayer unity game and I need to know:

Is it better performance to manage all connections from a single NetworkManager or break up user connections into multiple ones? I ask with respect to performance. So will this be more costly for my server or the reverse?

danke sehr

Answer (score 0):

ok so i thought about it a little more and since you can only have one active NetworkManager per scene (according to documentation ) I suppose I can't have multiple ones to break up connections as I was thinking.

My idea now is to use matchIds using Mirror but I'm stilling running into an issue. Collisions can still occur between GameObjects even though they have different matchIds.

Comment: If you have a new question, close this one ask a new question; don't post it as an answer.